# Is it possible to call functions in a remote shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, remote-access

I'm trying to remotely call a function defined in a shell script on a different server, and have that function run on the remote server.

Hopefully the following example should make this clear.

On host2 I have two scripts.

utils.sh:

```
f ()
{
  hostname
}
```

test.sh:

```
. utils.sh
f
```

On host2 I can then do the following:

```
host2:/tmp# ./test.sh
 host2
```

From host1, I want to be able to call the function `f` and have it run on host2 (so in this example, it would print "host2" since `f` just calls `hostname`). However, in fact I get the following error:

```
host1:~# ssh root@host2 /tmp/test.sh
 /tmp/test.sh: line 1: utils.sh: No such file or directory
 /tmp/test.sh: line 2: f: command not found
```

So, it's clear that test.sh is actually running on host1 - which is why it can't find /tmp/utils.sh (since that's only on host2) and correspondingly why if can't run function `f`.

**Is it possible to call a function in a remote shell script, and have it run on the remote machine?** Or is there anything else I can do to achieve a similar aim?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

Ah, there was a bug in my script.

test.sh should have been

```
. /tmp/utils.sh
f
```

I was missing the full path to the utils.sh script.

*-Edited to add:-*

Worth noting that it's not necessary to wrap the dotting in & function call in a new script - it is also possible to call directly like so:

```
host1:~# ssh root@host2 ". /tmp/utils.sh; f"
 host2
```